# How can I add Wordpress's 'nav_menu_link_attributes' to a specific menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress website that has multiple menus set up. I wanted to add custom attributes to the menu items in one of the menus using 'nav_menu_link_attributes', but that adds the attributes to all of the menus. How would I limit this to just one specific menu? I can't find any documentation on this question.

My current code is:

```
function add_menu_atts($atts){
  $atts['data-inventory-link'] = $atts['href'];
  $atts['data-model'] = $atts['title'];
  return $atts;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_menu_atts');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The filter you are using `nav_menu_link_attributes` supports other arguments as well. You can pass in a 2nd parameter `$item` and a 3rd parameter `$args` which contains the item details. Try something like this:

```
function add_menu_atts($atts, $item, $args){
  // your check for primary menu location
  if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
    $atts['data-inventory-link'] = $atts['href'];
    $atts['data-model'] = $atts['title'];
  }     

  return $atts;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_menu_atts', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!