# Add ROLE attribute to menu items

Tags: wordpress, menu, add-filter

I need to add a custom attribute to my menu items.

This is what I believe I have to do... but nothing is added.

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_role_attribute_to_menu' );
function add_role_attribute_to_menu( $atts ) {
  $atts['role'] = 'button';
  return $atts;
}
```

I'm using WP 5.6 and Astra free theme.

I noticed that also Astra uses this filter to add specific categories to the menu items, with no results!

What's the matter?
Maybe I have to include the `add_filter` inside another call?

I use [Elementor – Header, Footer & Blocks Template](https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-footer-elementor/) to manage the header of the site.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579279/how-can-i-add-wordpresss-nav-menu-link-attributes-to-a-specific-menu

Comment: Unfortunately this method does not work. I've alreay read that post.